# Custom foreach implementation in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to implement a custom iterator which works like `table.foreach` in Lua, but in more "syntax friendly" manner. I came across following construction (not sure if it's done purely in Lua or some kind of C "hack" in the Lua source code.

```lua
-- creature is a collection of Creature objects
-- "ps" is used as a filter variable

foreach creature cre "ps" do
    if cre.name ~= $name then
    -- code...
    end
end
```

I tried to play around with `table.foreach`, `ipairs` and so on - but can nowhere get the similar result to the mentioned code sample. Could you give me a hint how this could be implemented?

Comment: This is a syntax error in Lua; it can't be implemented in plain Lua. You could add a `foreach` keyword to the tokenizer, a production to the grammer etc. just to have some syntactic sugar that will stump every tool that supports Lua. Is it really worth it? Why is a standard Lua for loop like `for cre in creature:filter"ps" do ... end` not good enough? I find it more readable, and since it is just regular Lua, it will play nice with whatever tools you choose to use.

Comment: @Oka I would say brief - hence this question, if it's doable to implement this foreach keyword with iterators/next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new *keyword* requires either a [preproccesor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) or modifying the language's grammar [directly](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/).

An approximation of this syntax can already be easily achieved without leaving the confines of the language by writing an [*iterator*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5) - a function that when provided to the generic [`for`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5) continuously supplies values for the loop variables, until the first value it returns is *nil*.

(*More specifically, you usually write a function that creates (returns) an iterator. [`pairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pairs) and [`ipairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) are examples of this.*)

[`next`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next) is a function that when provided a *table* and a *key*, returns the *next* key and its associated value.

You can extend this with metatables and the `__call` metamethod to shorten the syntax required to construct the iterator (properly constructed classes / objects / prototypes (i.e., OOP) in Lua already rely heavily on metatables).

All this means that the syntax

```lua
for value in collection 'filter' do
    print(value)
end
```

is very achievable.

The full example, with a very basic iterator:

```lua
-- This is a live, proxied view into an existing table
local function View(t)
    local methods = {}

    local function match(value, filter)
        return type(value) == 'string' and value:match(filter)
    end

    function methods:filter(filter)
        local key, value

        return function (_)
            repeat
                key, value = next(t, key)
            until value == nil or match(value, filter)

            return value, key
        end
    end

    return setmetatable({}, {
        __index = methods,
        __metatable = false,
        __call = methods.filter
    })
end

local foo = View { 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd' }

-- :filter via __call
for value in foo '[ab]' do
    print(value)
end

print('-------')

-- explicitly
for value in foo:filter '[cd]' do
    print(value)
end

print('-------')

-- additional index variable
-- this is the inverse of the more typical `pairs` construct
for value, key in foo '[ad]' do
    print(key)
end
```

```
a
b
a
-------
c
c
d
-------
2
4
6
```

Comment: Is `__newindex = false` a fast-and-dirty way to implement read-only?

Comment: Uh, sort of - the runtime will explode if you attempt to plainly register a new index in that table :). `rawset` bypasses that. That part of the example isn't important, but I probably meant `__metatable = false` so that `methods` cannot be changed/referenced via the proxy/view (`getametatable`). I'll update the wording as its not exactly read-only.